How to avoid the entire app refresh on streamlit chat input
I have the following piece of code
def ask_q_n_a(data):
    question = streamlit.chat_input("Ask any question")
    if question:
        streamlit.write(ask_f(data, question))


the problem is as soon as the user enters the question the page refreshes and the entire app reloads fetching the data again. Using streamlit.cache_data() also doesn't help here . Any pointers??

There is a similar question in the streamlit forum here That might help. You might have a look at SessionState which is mentioned there.

It is normal for streamlit to rerun the code from top to bottom when users enters messages in the chat_input widget.
May I know what is ask_f(data, question). Perhaps that function also triggered a rerun.
